# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 1\ a>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

My attempt is:

As $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ then  $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} a^0 = 1$

It seems so easy for me that I'm starting to doubt about my solution. Is it all ok?

Comment: That's right.there is no error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing $x\to a^x$ is a continuous function, your answer is correct.